# Determine the end of one animation cycle

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

This was a slightly tricky one to search for. Not too sure what to bang into Google or SO, so I apologise if this has been answered before.

So I have two animations that I apply to a `CALayer` with a duration of 5 seconds (although this is not relevant) and they repeat indefinitely. I want to be able to gracefully remove these animations on user interaction.

Detecting the interaction is easy but being able to determine when the animations have reached the end of one cycle is not so easy. By detecting this I am hoping to achieve the effect of the animation finishing off it's last cycle and stopping, instead of harshly removing it from the screen which just look plain unfriendly.

This is what I am doing now and it is not working

```
- (void)attachFadeAnimation {

    // Create a fade animation that compliments the scale such that
    // the layer will become totally transparent 1/5 of the way
    // through the animation.
    CAKeyframeAnimation *fadeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnimation.values = @[@0.8, @0, @0];

    [self addAnimation:fadeAnimation withKeyPath:@"opacity"];

}

- (void)addAnimation:(CAKeyframeAnimation *)animation withKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {

    // These are all shared values of the animations and therefore
    // make more sense to be added here. Any changes here will
    // change each animation.
    animation.keyTimes = @[@0, @0.2, @1];
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    animation.duration = 5.0f;
    animation.delegate = self;

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:keyPath];

}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {

    if ( !self.emanating )
        [self.layer removeAllAnimations];

}
```

The delegate call to `animationDidStop:finished` is not called when I was expecting it to. Clearly I have misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: I think you want animationDidEnd not animationDidStop.

Comment: I don't think that method exists. At least it is not part of the CAAnimationDelegate protocol. Do you know where I could find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so failing with using delegate methods to achieve this I searched through the Apple CoreAnimation documentation to discover that the `CALayer` associated with my view carries a presentationLayer property which describes what is currently being displayed on the screen.

Using this I was able to create another animation to more gracefully "end" the first animation.

This code is actually from a different file as the original, but the effect I wished to achieve is the same:

```
- (void)alert {

    CABasicAnimation *flashAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    flashAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
    flashAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
    flashAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    flashAnimation.fromValue = (id)self.view.backgroundColor.CGColor;
    flashAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.58f green:0.23f blue:0.14f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:flashAnimation forKey:@"alert"];

}

- (void)cancelAlert {

    // Remove the flashing animation from the view layer.
    [self.view.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"alert"];

    // Using the views presentation layer I can interpolate the background
    // colour back to the original colour after removing the flashing
    // animation.
    CALayer *presentationLayer = (CALayer *)[self.view.layer presentationLayer];

    CABasicAnimation *resetBackground = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
    resetBackground.duration = 1.0f;
    resetBackground.fromValue = (id)presentationLayer.backgroundColor;
    resetBackground.toValue = (id)_originalBackgroundColor.CGColor;

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:resetBackground forKey:@"reset"];

}
```

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the correct one, for future reference.